# how to use cocos2d-python draw a circle

Tags: python, cocos2d-iphone

Python version: V3.6.1
cocos2d version: v0.6.5  (python.cocos2d.org)
I tried to draw a circle using cocos2d, but failed.
cocos2d turtorial don't mentioned about this function, and cannot find any instructions from the web, thanks for your help.
code:

---

```
import cocos
class Ant(cocos.layer.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ant, self).__init__()
        centerPoint=cocos.draw.Vector2(200,200)
        circle=cocos.draw.Circle(centerPoint, 30.0)
        self.add(circle)

cocos.director.director.init(width=640, height=480)
scene=cocos.scene.Scene(Ant())
cocos.director.director.run(scene)
```

---

warning:
'Circle' object has no attribute 'on_enter'
File: C:\Users\gshao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cocos\cocosnode.py, Line: 611